# Printing field 1 and the even number fields using paste and awk

Tags: bash, awk, paste

I have two folders, folder1_a and folder2_a, with different file.txt in each. Each file.txt has two columns and six rows. I want to print field 1 of the first file and the second column of each file, column-wise.
This command got me the second/even fields:

```
$ paste folder[1-2]*/file.txt | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) $i="" }1'
col2  col4
 7  g
 8  h
 9  i
 10  j
 11  k
 12  l
```

The following command (I know it has weird syntax) got me the fields I wanted, but the even fields are "pushed" one row lower

```
$ paste folder[1-2]*/file.txt | awk '{print $1}  {for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2)}1'
col1
 col2  col4
1
 7  g
2
 8  h
3
 9  i
4
 10  j
5
 11  k
6
 12  l
```

I know I can use $1, $2, $4 ... but what if I have more files and I don't want to manually list all columns?

Files:

```
$ cat folder1_a/file.txt
col1    col2
1   7
2   8
3   9
4   10
5   11
6   12

$ cat folder2_a/file.txt
col3    col4
a   g
b   h
c   i
d   j
e   k
f   l
```

Comment: I don't see the commands that you have tried. You should also provide sample data for the two input files, not just the output result.

Comment: please update the question to show the (correct) expected output

Comment: what is the field delimiters for both files? can any of the columns contain white space?

Comment: `print` adds a newline after its output. Use the more flexible `printf` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumptions:

- field delimiters can be any white space, eg: (multiple) spaces and/or tabs
- column values do not contain embedded white space

Tweaking OP's current code:

```
$ paste folder[1-2]*/file.txt | awk '{printf "%s",$1; for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) printf "%s%s",OFS,$i; print ""}'
col1 col2 col4
1 7 g
2 8 h
3 9 i
4 10 j
5 11 k
6 12 l
```

---

Once you bring `awk` into the mix there's a good chance you can do all the work in `awk`, eg:

```
awk '
    { lines[FNR]= lines[FNR] (FNR==NR ? $1 : "") OFS $2 }
END { for (i=1;i<=FNR;i++) print lines[i] }
' <list_of_files>
```

If we replace `<list_of_files>` with `folder[1-2]*/file.txt` we get:

```
col1 col2 col4
1 7 g
2 8 h
3 9 i
4 10 j
5 11 k
6 12 l
```

Comment: OK for the type of data we have to deal here, but in general, `printf %s ....` would be safer.

Comment: Can you explain what `print ""` does?

Comment: the `printf's` leave the cursor on the current line; once we're at the end of the line we need to terminate the line (typically print a `\n`); if you know for a fact you wish to end a line with `\n` you could use `printf "\n"`; alternatively, you can explicitly print the ouput field separator (`printf "%s", OFS`); another approach is to print an empty string - `print ""` (notice we're using `print` and not `printf`) - this won't add any characters to the end of the line and it will implicitly print whatever's defined as the default `OFS` (typically a `\n`, but could be user-defined)

Answer (score 1):

As your files are small you could do all this with just `awk`:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[FNR]=$0; next} {$1=a[FNR]; a[FNR]=$0}
  END {for(n in a) print a[n]}' folder*/file.txt
col1 col2 col4
1    7    g
2    8    h
3    9    i
4    10   j
5    11   k
6    12   l
```

The first block is applied to the first file only (`FNR == NR`) and just stores the full lines in array `a`, indexed by line number (starting from 1). The second block applies to all other files and replaces the first field of each line by the corresponding entry in array `a` before storing the modified line back in array `a`. The `END` block prints the content of array `a`.

This should work for any number of input files and any number of fields per file: all lines number `n` have their first field removed, except for the first file, and are concatenated together. Example with a third file (which is just a repetition of the first):

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[FNR]=$0; next} {$1=a[FNR]; a[FNR]=$0}
  END {for(n in a) print a[n]}' folder*/file.txt folder1_a/file.txt
col1 col2 col4 col2
1    7    g    7
2    8    h    8
3    9    i    9
4    10   j    10
5    11   k    11
6    12   l    12
```

Example with a third column (`col2.5`, content `2.5`) added to your first file:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[FNR]=$0; next} {$1=a[FNR]; a[FNR]=$0}
  END {for(n in a) print a[n]}' folder*/file.txt
col1 col2 col2.5 col4
1    7    2.5    g
2    8    2.5    h
3    9    2.5    i
4    10   2.5    j
5    11   2.5    k
6    12   2.5    l
```

Comment: Can you explain in details this par
`{$1=a[FNR]; a[FNR]=$0}
  END {for(n in a) print a[n]}'`
I don't have a very strong background in awk. Thank you!

Comment: As written in the answer `$1=a[FNR]` replaces the first field of the line (`$1`) with entry number `FNR` of array `a` (`FNR`is the awk variable that contains the line number in the current file). `a[FNR]=$0` stores the modified line in entry number `FNR` of array `a`. As its name suggests the `END` block is executed after all files have been processed. Here it simply loops over all indexes of array `a` and prints the corresponding entry.